Pourquoi zero article après avoir
Dans la phrase suivante:

Sa nourriture n'a pas bon goût

Pourquoi on n'a pas  utilisé un article après  le verbe avoir (de bon goût/ un bon goût).

Sa nourriture n'a pas un bon goût est ici possible mais c'est moins courant.
Après le verbe avoir, l'article est en effet souvent omis dans beaucoup d'expressions plus ou moins figées qui remontent à une époque où le besoin d'un article ne se faisait pas sentir :

Tu as raison, il a peur, on a faim, j'ai bon espoir, si j'ai bonne mémoire, ils n'ont pas confiance, etc.

Voir aussi :

Expressions idiomatiques avec avoir

Why is the partitive article missing from "on ne gardait pas trace de ces choses-là"?

Quelles expériences s'utilisent sans l'article partitif ?

Avoir bonne/mauvaise réputation – absence d’article


